# Triangle inequality average

Tags: algorithms, fractals

This may not be the proper place for this post, but I think it is more fitting here than stackoverflow.

I am attempting to implement the triangle inequality average fractal coloring algorithm based off the following paper:
http://jussiharkonen.com/files/on_fractal_coloring_techniques%28lo-res%29.pdf

I have a working julia set being displayed but haven't been able to get the TIA coloring to work. While the julia set is iterating toward the max itr/escape size, an average angle is calculated. That average angle is used to color the graph. I have followed along closely to the paper but my results are nothing like what is show.

I am not really sure where I could be going wrong.

My example:
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Md3fDs

Goal:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0hUT.jpg

I believe my algorithm is calculating the angle correctly, but I am not sure why my colorings are looking the way they do.

NOTE:

If this post seems off topic, let me know and I will move it.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/triangle_ineq